# HTML/CSS vertical navigation bar still horizontal?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am trying to make a vertical navigation bar for mobile phones, but it looks like CSS is not good. Could someone see whats wrong?
Ill post pictures as soon as possible.

HTML CODE

```css
#navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav-active {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #1b9cc6;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#clients">CLIENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#work">WORK</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

EDIT: Here is the immage. Sorry for not cropping it, but I cant find a proper tool for Linux.
[image]

Comment: Do you want the nav items to be in a row(horizontal), or underneath each other(vertical)?

Comment: The links are just too big in that size to be vertically aligned. Use Media Queries or Bootstrap to help you in responsive design

Comment: Can you show more of the CSS? What you're showing here is not enough to generate the screen shot, so the problem must be with the bits you're not showing!

Comment: Also, off topic, but I'm not sure what you mean with "a proper tool for Linux". Were you looking for gpaint?

Comment: Update: I believe the problem was in media queries. There was one style that was not defined for width.

Answer (score 0):

Man, your `#navigation` takes the `width` of `100%`. It takes a hundred percent of your screen width. Try changing it with a much smaller value.